# Is there any way i can trigger the onEnded attribute on the video element while testing using jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

i've been trying to test this component using jest but I've not been able to find a way around it.

```
function TestUseStateObject() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(true);
  const handleAdd = () => {
    console.log('setting state');
    setState(false)
  }
  console.log('state > ', state);
  if(!state) {
    return (<p>Testing</p>)
  }
  return (
    <video src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4" autoPlay controls onEnded={() => handleAdd()} />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I finally found the answer after struggling for hours!

### Using React testing library:

```js
fireEvent.ended(videoElement);
```

The long form way to do the same is

```js
const endedEvent = createEvent('ended', element);
fireEvent(element, endedEvent);
```

(The other answers provided here create an `'onEnded'` event, which is not an event type, as the event is actually called `'ended'`)

Answer (score 1):

**Using React testing library:**

```
const onEndedEvent = createEvent('onEnded', element);
fireEvent(element, onEndedEvent);
```

Answer from Klugjo was almost there, but he missed off that you need to include the element in the createEvent function call. Above is a working example.

Comment: This solution does not seem to be working for me. For me, the onEnded function is never run when calling `fireEvent` like described here

Answer (score 0):

**With Enzyme:**

https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/simulate.html

```
const wrapper = mount(<TestUseStateObject />);

wrapper.find('video').simulate('ended');
```

**With React Testing Library:**

https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events#createeventeventname

```
// simulate the 'onEnded' event on a video component
fireEvent(
  videoNode,
  createEvent('ended', element)
)
```

Comment: "onEnded" is not correct. The event name should be "ended", at least in react-testing-library. See my other answer for how that can be used